# Oracle Database - Grant/Revoke High Concurrency

Tags: oracle, concurrency, oracle10g, sql-grant

We have an **Oracle 10g release 2** database running on a production environment. It's experiencing a lot of concurrency, as Sql Developer 17.4 "Waits for past 1 hour" graph shows.

When the database is behaving slow, we take a look at that graph, and it shows a very high concurrency. We noticed that when this occurs almost always a GRANT/REVOKE is executing.

Are DDL's like GRANTS/REVOKES capable of generating this high concurrency ? Do DDL's always generate locks ? Can those locks be disabled ?

Could you guys point us on the right direction ?

Comment: See [Automatic Locks in DDL Operations](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/ap_locks002.htm#SQLRF55509). In short - each DDL command modyfies dictionary data and must hold an exclusive lock on database objects.Grant is not supposed to be executed as a "normal" command by the application during it's normal operation but rather it is considered as "administrative" action that should be run only once. If your system runs many grants, it's a sign of bad design, this affects performance, you need to change this. I vote to close this question.

Comment: how many grants ? Is it better for performance to use roles ? When an user is created in our system it triggers 50 grants more or less. We need to give him access to different tables (select, update, delete). The thing is that users are created all the time, its a distributed administration.